# Apache MINA SFTP - add callback methods after successful file transfers

Tags: ssh, sshd, apache-mina

Am using Apache Mina to build my own SFTP server. I want to notify a server automatically after each file transfer is complete. Please help me with some pointers in this direction.

Ideally, there should be an interface that I need to implement and a class where I need to register my call back function. I know that Apache MIna SSHD uses Apache Mina under the hood which has IO events, handlers and filters to accomplish this.

I am looking for something more concrete. Classes and method names to register my callback function would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar using an earlier version of Mina SSHD.  I ended up creating my own implementation of `FileSystemFactory`, `FileSystemView`, and `SshFile`.  The `SshFile` interface has callback methods for `create()`, `delete()`, `createOutputStream()`, etc.  If someone has a simpler, more elegant solution I would be very interested to see it.